# trying to deploy teamcity into googlecloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, teamcity

I am trying to follow this page from jetbrains: -

https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2019/03/teamcity-google-cloud-deployment/

I have enabled the APIs, I have created an external IP address, I have setup my A record, and it resolves correctly. So then I follow the next step  and in my google cloud console I am issuing the following:-

> gcloud deployment-manager deployments create  --template https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JetBrains/teamcity-google-template/master/teamcity.jinja --properties zone:,ipAddress:,domainName:,domainOwnerEmail:

I have filled in the fields with the relevant values, and I press return.

It looks like its chuntering away for a bit and then I get the error message

"Creation of legacy mode networks is deprecated. Please create a subnet mode network instead by removing the IPv4Range field and adding the autoCreateSubnetworks field to your network insert request.","reason":"badRequest"}],"message":"Creation of legacy mode networks is deprecated. Please create a subnet mode network instead by removing the IPv4Range field and adding the autoCreateSubnetworks field to your network insert request.... "

I have no clue what this means or what I do to make it work

I was surpised as this was only from march 2019 on the jetbrains site, and the instructions don't seem to work, I am quite familiar with teamcity, using it every day for the last 8 years, but i'm not at all familiar with google cloud, so I need some pointers or instruction on how to do this...

Regards Julian

Answer (score 0):

I think that this error is related to this [line](https://github.com/JetBrains/teamcity-google-template/blob/master/network.jinja#L22) which still trying to use legacy-network CDIR. However, seems that using legacy-networks is [deprecated](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-legacy) in favor of subnet mode networks. Also referenced [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/networks).

So, you can create an issue on JetBrains side for them to fix this.